# Perl script that copies files listed in text file only copies the last file successfully

Tags: perl, file-io, copy

I have a Perl script that reads in a list of files from a file, `accessFiles.txt`,  and copies them to another location.

```
open my $accessFiles, "$scriptDir\\accessFiles.txt" or die "Could not open access file list $!";

while (my $accessFile = <$accessFiles>) {
    my($file, $dir, $ext) = fileparse($accessFile, qr/\.[^.]*/);
    my $accessDir = "$localDir\\AccessFiles\\$file";
    my $accessCopy = "$accessDir\\$file$ext";

    system("rmdir","/S", "/Q",$accessDir);
    system("mkdir",$accessDir);
    system("copy", $accessFile, $accessCopy);
}
```

The output of the copy command says it copied one file for each file in `accessFiles.txt`, but only the last file gets copied.

I've added input statements before and after the copy, and I cannot see any of the other files in the copied directory at any time.

Now, if I change the script to read from an array of files, then it works perfectly.

```
my @files = ('\\\\sourceshare\acc1.accdb', '\\\\sourceshare\acc2.accdb');

foreach my $accessFile (@files) {
    my($file, $dir, $ext) = fileparse($accessFile, qr/\.[^.]*/);
    my $accessDir = "$localDir\\AccessFiles\\$file";
    my $accessCopy = "$accessDir\\$file$ext";
    system("rmdir","/S", "/Q",$accessDir);
    system("mkdir",$accessDir);
    system("copy", $accessFile, $accessCopy);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't remove the trailing newline. Add

```
chomp($accessFile);
```